# Apply a function to all list elements

Tags: java, list

I am trying to apply the same function to a list of elements in an easy way. Some Examples

Capitalise all strings:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("foo");
list.add("bar");
list.forEach(s -> s.toUpperCase());
System.out.println(list);
```

Multiply by 3

```
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(2);
list.add(5);
list.forEach(i -> i * 3);
System.out.println(list2);
```

Which doesen't obviously change anything.

Do I really need a for loop like

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("foo");
list.add("bar");

List<String> upper = new ArrayList<>();
for(int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++){
    upper.add(list.get(x).toUpperCase());
}
System.out.println(upper);
```

or is there a shorter way?

Comment: `list.stream().map(s -> s.toUpperCase()).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: `list.stream().map(String::toUpperCase).forEach(System.out::println);`